# How to fix 'Active: active (exited)' issue in Cassandra server?

Tags: database, ubuntu, server, cassandra

I'm installing a new cassandra database server and want to run the same successfully.  How to fix the exited state issue?

This is for a new Ubuntu server.

Active: active (exited)

I want it to be active and running normally but, it is in exited state.

Comment: what version of Ubuntu, Java, and Cassandra?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 (LTS) x64, openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16, OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3), OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.04.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Cassandra version 3.11.4

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same.
This is what i did to solve mine.

1. Cassandra does seem not to be working with Java 11
2. install java 8 by runing this command: sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre
3. Run the following command to chose the java 8: sudo update-alternatives --config java
4. reboot you ubuntun computer or VM
5. start cassandra: sudo service cassandra start
6. check cassandra status: service cassandra status

Comment: This worked for me, but is there a way to change the jdk without rebooting?

Answer (score 2):

Java 11 support seems to be experimental indeed. After I installed Java and Cassandra I got it running.

For java, I used

sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre

sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk

and set

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

in /etc/environment. Please note, I have also rebooted the station, once after Java installation and JAVA_HOME setting, and another time after Cassandra installation.

My Ubuntu is 18.04.01,

the command "java -version" prints

openjdk version "1.8.0_252"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~18.04-b09)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)

and

the command "cqlsh" prints

Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.

[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.6 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]

Use HELP for help.

cqlsh>

and the terminal presents the cql shell.

Answer (score 0):

Currently released version of Cassandra doesn't support Java 11. You need to install Java 8 to run Cassandra on your machine.

Comment: I have the same issue. I run Cassandra 4, java 8,  cqlsh 6.0.0, and the active is exited. I did all the post's hint and the issue did not fix. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check for folders inside / var / lib / cassandra

folders are
commitlog, data, hints, saved_caches

give them rights (I gave 777) it worked, fixed active (exited) and with this nodetool status connection failed 127.0.0.1

Comment: having 777 on the data folders is very bad idea... this means that anybody on the server can modify or delete your data...